# Is there any way to make a delay in microseconds in STM32 CubeIDE?

Tags: embedded, stm32

As I mentioned, I need to make 30us delay to init my sensor in proper way.

Comment: delay from where? after powerup? after sensor powerup? after main loop entry? Does it have to be exactly 30us or just "a bit of time"? does the uC have to do anything meanwhile or will a simple ```sleep(1)``` do the trick?

Comment: The _proper_ way would be to use on-chip hardware peripheral times, then set one up. Or a RTC peripheral if available.

Comment: Data Watchpoint Trigger (DWT Delay) method can create us delays

Answer (score 3):

You can only do it blocking way:

```
#define SYSTICKCLOCK 120000000ULL
#define SYSTICKPERUS (SYSTICKCLOCK / 1000000UL)

// delay has to constant expression
static void inline __attribute__((always_inline)) delayus(unsigned delay)
{
    uint32_t ticks = SYSTICKPERUS * delay;
    uint32_t start_tick = SysTick -> VAL;

    while(SysTick -> VAL - start_tick < ticks);
}
```

Of course you need to define SYSTICKCLOCK to match your clock settings.

Comment: Why would you say that you can only do it blocking? If you can have a SysTick, you can have a SysTick callback => I found a non-blocking way.

Comment: @Max 30 **micro** seconds.

Comment: yeah, whats the problem with that. I'm using a 1us SysTick callback most of the time and have used interrupts with higher precision.

Comment: @Max Good luck - so your uC is almost only dealing with systick. Good design :) And if your clock is below 40Mhz it will take the whole core time to handle the systick. Great

Comment: You could use an interrupt to yield a "one shot" timer but then the interrupt latency will affect the result somewhat. All of course depending on what clock speed you are running at.

Comment: As for this code here, using 64 bit arithmetic is usually not a great idea on 32 bitters like Cortex M. The 64 bit software lib itself might just much away more than 30us.

Comment: @Max What part is that, some Cortex A or DSP etc? This was tagged STM32 so most likely it's a Cortex M.

Comment: @Lundin Where are you see 64 bits arithmetic? Constant expressions? They are calculated compile time  (see my comment about the `delay` parameter which should be constant expression as well

Comment: @Lundin Example: https://godbolt.org/z/Ev6oMoPWK

Comment: Here: `SYSTICKPERUS * delay;`. This is carried out in 64 bits and it is not a compile-time integer constant expression. At -O3 the compiler luckily managed to optimize it out (this time). Remove optimization and you get 6 instructions for that line, ok not super terrible but still needless.

Comment: @Lundin removing optimizations completely makes no sense at all. `-Og` it is a minimum one which makes sense (it is for debugging - very light optimizations which does not change the program flow - thus you can step through the code) https://godbolt.org/z/8qaWxTr9P . BTW I am not lucky - it is how all known to me toolchains behave (gcc, iar, GH, keil)

Comment: @Lundin many vendor supplied libraries eve use real numbers for the compile time computations (for example delay function in avr-gcc toolchain :) )

Comment: My point is that in this specific case you got away with using 64 bits arithmetic mostly by chance. In another scenario where optimizations can't be carried out, you get unnecessarily slow code. Like when implicit promotion changes a parameter to signed type or similar.